# htaccess rewrite only working without "www" and "https"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this case where the rewrite only works without www and https, this is `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)/1348-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html$ /$1/3016-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

this URL works and redirects:

```
http://example.com/en/car-accessories/1348-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html
```

this one doesn't:

```
https://www.example.com/en/car-accessories/1348-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html
```

any ideas? I spent a good few hours on this without any solution, not sure what's wrong. The rule is on top of the `.htaccess` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This suggests an "error" in your server config, either `.htaccess` files are not enabled for the other vHost(s) (eg. HTTPS) or they are pointing to a different area of the filesystem. But presumably your site works OK (apart from the redirect), so maybe the former? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have access to the server config? What about `https://example.com` (with HTTPS and without www)?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by doesn't work ? Is the 2nd URL even redirecting ? If you are on a Linux platform you might want to try `curl -L --head <url>`, then you can see if redirections or taking place (or a redirection loop). Actually `curl` is a better way to test your rules, because your browser cache could be playing tricks on you.

Note that `$1` is the first captured group from your regular expression. So you should add the host you want to redirect to ie:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)/1348-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html$  https://example.com/$1/3016-duracell-32-aaa-pack.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Otherwise the browser is very likely going to keep using the current host name. If you don't provide a full URL, then it has to make up for the missing bits.

But if all you want is remove `/en/` from the URL, then you could write a simpler and more straightforward rule.

Comment: "if all you want is remove `/en/`..." - Although they are also changing the numeric "id" from `1348` to `3016`.